# Merging Multiple columns data to a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has data like as following

```
Name |Reg_Type

aaa   reg_type1

aaa   reg_type2

bbb   reg_type3

aaa   reg_type5

bbb   reg_type4

bbb   reg_type1
```

However, I want a sql for returning result set like:-

```
Name| Reg_type1|  Reg_type2  |Reg_type3  |Reg_type4  |Reg_type5  |Reg_type6

aaa      Y          Y            N           N          Y            N
bbb      Y          N            Y           Y          N            N
```

Comment: Do you want separate columns or do you want the values concatenated?

Answer (score 2):

The listagg function is what you need. You can learn about it here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

```
SELECT name, LISTAGG(REG_TYPE,'|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY reg_type) AS REG
FROM REG
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: hey everyone i want a separate column. Reg_type1,Reg_type2,Reg_type3.... are all separate columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try a pivot query:

```
select * from mytable
  pivot (count(reg_type)
           for reg_type in ('reg_type1',
                            'reg_type2',
                            'reg_type3',
                            'reg_type4',
                            'reg_type5'));
```

which gives results:

```
NAME    'REG_TYPE1'  'REG_TYPE2'  'REG_TYPE3'  'REG_TYPE4'  'REG_TYPE5'
aaa      2            1            0            0            1
bbb      0            0            1            1            0
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33f23/9).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

In Oracle, the concatenation operator is ||.  So, it would be

Select Name || '|' || Reg_type1 || '|' || Reg_type2 ..... from tablename .....

Comment: there is no Reg_type<n> column